# Determinant of a matrix with variables in it

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Assuming that $z \neq  0$, compute the determinant $d_n(z) = \det D_n \left(1, z, 1 - \frac{1}{z^2} \right)$, where $z$ is a complex variable. In particular, compute the value $d_n(\sqrt{2})$.

This matrix looks like this:

$$\pmatrix{z& 1 - \frac{1}{z^2} & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 1 & z & 1 - \frac{1}{z^2} & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & z & 1 - \frac{1}{z^2} &... &0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & z &... &0\\ : & : & : & : & ... & : \\   \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &... & z}.$$

Now to solve it, blah blah blah, you do the whole decomposition thing and I end up with

$$d_n = zd_{n-1} - \left(1 - \frac{1}{z^2} \right) d_{n-2},$$

and so from here, I get the characteristic polynomial to be

$$x^2 - z x + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{z^2} \right) = 0,$$

which, according to the answers, is correct. Now, I need to solve this and so I get two roots and then I can use the formulas to find the determinant. So to solve it, I said let's first multiply through by $z^2$ to get rid of the denominator and then use the quadratic formula to solve. So multiplying through gives me

$$z^2 x^2 - z^3x + (z^2 - 1) = 0,$$

and then putting this into the quadratic formula gives me

$$x_{1,2} = \frac{z^3 \pm \sqrt{z^6 - (4 \cdot z^2 \cdot(z^2 - 1))}}{2z^2} = \frac{z^3 \pm \sqrt{z^6 - 4z^4 + 4z^2}}{2z^2}$$

which can be simplified to give me

$$\frac{z \pm \sqrt{z^4 - 4z^2 + 4}}{2} = \frac{z \pm \sqrt{(z^2 - 2)^2}}{2} = \frac{z \pm z^2 - 2}{2}.$$

This then ends up giving me two more qudratics to solve, when in the answers it says the roots to that characteristic polynomial should be

$$\frac{1}{z} \hspace{1cm} \mathrm{and} \hspace{1cm} z - \frac{1}{z}.$$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @julien It is $d_{n-2}$ because I decompose with the $1 - \frac{1}{z}$ and then in my matrix of minors I decompose with respect to the $1$ in row $2$ column $1$ and that gives me $d_{n-2}$. EDIT: Sorry, I think you misunderstood the matrix. Let me write in one more row.

Comment: @julien Yeah sorry, I was lazy with the matrix. I've added in an extra row.

Comment: No they don't. Because I get my exact same matrix again, with just two rows and columns gone, hence $d_{n-2}$. Literally just cover up rows $1$ and $2$ and columns $1$ and $2$ and you'll see there's no triangular matrix.

Comment: The mistake isn't in that bit. The mistake is in solving for the roots.

Comment: Sorry, I did not check your edit carefully enough. The recurrence formula is correct.

Comment: If you take the sum and the product of the two roots they give you recover the coefficients of the recurrence equation. So that's correct. The problem is in your manipulation of the square root. It is multivalued on $\mathbb{C}$, so you can't write $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$. What about $\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$ for instance? The lhs has one answer, while the rhs has $2\times 2$ answers $\pm i\cdot\pm i$ which end up giving $2$ answers $\pm 1$.

Comment: Hmmm. Well I also thought about if I don't multiply by $z^2$ first, wait until its under the square root and then multiply everything under the square root by $z^2$, but I end up with the same answer. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You have to be careful with the complex square root. But here it is fine. $\sqrt{z^2(z^2-2)^2}$ has indeed two solutions $\pm z(z^2-2)$, so you get $\frac{z^3\pm z(z^2-2)}{2z^2}=\frac{z}{2}\pm\frac{z}{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{z^2}\right)$, that is $\frac{1}{z}$ and $z-\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Why is it ok here? And how comes it doesn't work if I try and do it my way? By my way, sorry, I meant the way I did it first

Comment: The mistake you made is that you simplified $\frac{z}{2z^2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, I think. And I am just saying: be careful when you manipulate the square root, as shown by the example I gave above ($1=(-1)(-1)$). If you keep track of all the possible square roots, that's fine. Then $\sqrt{1}$ would be, for instance, $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Kaish, when you factored out the $z^2$ term from inside the square root, you appear to have forgotten that this will become $z$ and thus it will not completely cancell with the $z^2$ on the denominator. Instead, you should have written: $\frac{z³ \pm z\sqrt{z^4 - 4z^2 + 4}}{2z²} = \frac{z \pm \frac{1}{z}\sqrt{(z^2 - 2)^2}}{2} = \frac{z \pm z - 2/z}{2}=z-1/z,1/z$. But also you already have a quadratic in $x$ and you don't need to multiply that by anything, $z$ is not the variable you are trying to solve in, you are trying to solve in $x$ the expressions in $z$ may as well be called a, b & c.